# Nginx HTTP to HTTPS 301 loop redirect

Tags: nginx, https, http-status-code-301

I need to make HTTP->HTTPS redirection for whole site, but every time I get error message with 301 loop redirection. Please correct my conf to not get 301 error.Here is my conf file:

```
upstream live {
  server IP:PORT;
  }
server {
      listen      80 default;
      server_name mysite.com;
      access_log  off;
      error_log   off;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
      index index.html index.htm;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
      listen 443;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
      index index.html index.htm;
      rewrite_log on;
      server_name mysite.com;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
      client_max_body_size 200m;

      location / {
        index index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$uri&$args;
      }

      location /web {
        proxy_pass https://live/gateway/web;
        proxy_set_header "MP_FRONT" aaa;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
      }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just try to replace first server JSON like below

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

please, try and let me know its working for you or not

Comment: Currently it's redirecting to https with the same loop, browser shows error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS